# NSURLConnection waits for server to finish processing before returning response - browser doesn't

Tags: php, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I've built an iOS Application that frequently connects to my server via NSURLConnection. It's a pretty standard setup; the app sends various information to the server, and the server returns a JSON response based on the information it received.

In a new feature i've built - it requires a particular PHP script to do alot of processing, and instead of giving the application a response after the server has finished, i'd like to give the application a response before it starts processing - which is what i cannot achieve.

A basic rundown of the PHP is as follows:

```
<?
echo "Output buffering is " . ini_get('output_buffering') . "<br />";
// NM testing ob buffer technique

ob_start(); 

$profiles_ar = array(
    "reach" => 10,
);

$return_ar = array(
    "success"   => $profiles_ar['reach'],
);

echo json_encode($return_ar);                   // Note the buffer must be "filled" with 4096 characters (bytes?) for ob_flush() to work before sleep() occurs.

for($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++)
{
    echo " ";
    ob_flush(); flush;
}

echo $buffer;

ob_flush();

flush();

ob_end_flush();

for($i=0;$i < $profiles_ar['reach']; $i++)
{
   sleep(1);
}

echo "finshed: ".$i;

ob_flush();

flush();

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

The script above works perfectly fine in a browser - {"success":10} is immediately outputted. If this script is accessed from my iOS Application however, {"success":10} is received after the for loop has finished.

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which of the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods are you using to retrieve the data?

Comment: connectionDidFinishLoading. I've just done some logging and i'm getting an instant response in didReceiveData! Thanks for your help. It isn't necessarily the fix I was hoping for (since this method is called multiple times throughout a request) but a fix is a fix nonetheless.